# Does the output voltage of a boost converter without load approach infinity?

Tags: voltage, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, inductor, boost

[image: Text]

*where R is an open contact*

If I understand it correctly for a given square waveform the energy stored in L is constant for every charge cycle(part of the cycle when S is closed). When S is opened L tries to maintain the current which was previously flowing through it. So L initially creates a voltage V such that

(V-Cv)/esr = I   <=>   V = (I*esr)+Cv

where Cv is the voltage at the capacitor and I is the current previously flowing through L. Since I>0 and esr>0 => V>Cv. Thus every cycle charge flows into the capacitor, increasing its voltage.

Yet when I simulated the circuit on https://www.falstad.com/circuit/ the output voltage hits an upper bound. Is this a case of limited monotone growth? That doesn't seem to make sense to me either because I don't see how the energy in L can be dissipated.

Comment: Basically yes. Voltage will rise until something breaks, either some semiconductor or capacitor heating up a lot due to voltage overstress before shorting, or a flashover.

Comment: Do you include the R in the simulation?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some components:

Real switches and diodes have capacitance, and real inductors have losses (and capacitance!).

Even assuming a perfectly fast switch (which isn't even a terrible assumption, as real switches can be turned off on par or faster than the voltage rises due to capacitance), the peak voltage will be given by: \$V_\textrm{pk} \le V_\textrm{in} + I_{L\textrm{(pk)}} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$.  The inequality is due to losses; even a fairly lossy inductor doesn't lose much in the first 1/4 cycle, but real inductors are not lossless so it will be strictly less in that case, and only equal in the ideal case.

Basically, for short pulses (low currents), what you are doing is charging the inductor to some point along its RLC free-ringdown waveform, then letting it go at those initial conditions (supply voltage and peak current).

In fact, normally we give waveforms in switching converters as a roughly-constant slope, square waves with some rise/fall time; but this is an approximation, and what's seen is really a small segment of this ringdown curve -- the full amplitude of which would simply be much too large for the circuit, so it's immediately clamped by the diode or whatever, and looks nearly straight.

For larger pulses and no diode clamp, the full magnitude may indeed be visible, at least up until switch breakdown occurs.

Note that, for MOSFET type switches, the body diode will clamp a negative-going ringdown, flattening out the peak and stretching it in time.  So the above may be true for the positive (boost) phase, but not on the backswing.  We can use a diode in series with the MOSFET to avoid this, or use a naturally-rectifying device like an SCR or vacuum tube.

Answer (score 1):

If the simulator uses a capacitor model which accounts for leakage current, then the voltage is bounded even without considering the fact that real world components will eventually break. The circuit will reach equilibrium near a voltage Vo where the energy developed in the inductor in one switching period is about equal to the energy lost via leakage in the capacitor in one switching period.

Leakage current in real capacitors increases with voltage, but even if it was constant, this would still be true (energy lost via constant leakage current would increase as the voltage across the cap increases.)

Leakage current is intentionally small in most real capacitors, so you'd be hard pressed to build a real circuit that reaches this equilibrium before something breaks.

Answer (score 0):

> *Does the output voltage of a boost converter without load approach
> infinity?*

A boost converter (even with the tiniest of duty cycles) causes current to ramp upwards in the inductor and, as with any inductor, if you open circuit it without providing a circuit path for the stored energy, there can be sparks or voltage breakdown (back-emf).

However, even the inductors parasitic capacitance can limit the back-emf so, it's probably not useful to talk about infinity here.

But you have an output capacitor and, that should always be present (not load dependent). So **it** will acquire the energy from the inductor and increase the output voltage. Clearly on many consecutive cycles of switching the inductor, the output voltage across the capacitor will progressively rise (in steps) until such point as the capacitor fails or the diode fails or the transistor switch fails.

Your falsestad simulator doesn't appear to indicate what you are seeing. Maybe you have set it up differently?